# what is the purpose of ...this.props.pokemon and how's it different from this.props.pokemon

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on a simple react project wherein I found this snippet

```
 let hand1 =[]
    let hand2 =[ ...this.props.pokemon];
    while(hand1.length < hand2.length){
        let randIdx = Math.floor(Math.random()*hand2.length);
        let randPokemon = hand2.splice(randIdx,1)[0];
        hand1.push(randPokemon)
    }
```

What is the use of ..this.props.pokemon here?

Comment: Do you mean about [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)?

Comment: It uses the [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a copy of the array so you don't mutate the one in props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **It is [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)**

In your case, it deep copy `pokemon` array from your `props` and prevent mutate the original array/object

**Take a look at this example where `spread syntax` is not used:**

```js
const firstArray = [1, 2];

const secondArray = firstArray;

secondArray[0] = 9;

console.log(firstArray);
```

**And here is when `spread syntax` is used**

```js
const firstArray = [1, 2];

const secondArray = [...firstArray];

secondArray[0] = 9;

console.log(firstArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let hand2 = [ ...this.props.pokemon]
```

The above expression takes all the values inside `this.props.pokemon` and puts it inside the `hand2` array.

For eg:

```
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana']
const breakfast = [...fruits, 'milk']

console.log(breakfast) -> ['apple', 'banana', 'milk']
```

Whereas if you don't have the spread operator(...). It'll put the whole array there instead of just the values. For eg:

```
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana']
const breakfast = [fruits, 'milk']

console.log(breakfast) -> [['apple', 'banana'], 'milk']
```